# Why is dplyr summarize na.rm not working?

Tags: r

The na.rm=TRUE function within the sd function in my code is not removing the Na's from my table. I'm not sure why this is happening or how to fix this. I know some of my datapoints are singletons so the sd should just be 0 next to the mean.

Here is the dput() of my table.

```
> dput(n11.stat)
structure(list(Family = structure(1:11, levels = c("Adoxaceae", 
"Anacardiaceae", "Apiaceae", "Asteraceae", "Cornaceae", "Ericaceae", 
"Fabaceae", "Oleaceae", "Pinaceae", "Plantaginaceae", "Rosaceae"
), class = "factor"), count = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 4L), mean = c(4.95, 5.285, 16.34, 24.286, 5.75, 15.13, 
7.75333333333333, 44.39, 29.56, 9.01, 5.7), sd = c(2.67286363288515, 
4.23556961930742, NA, 11.2702542118623, NA, NA, 3.17789762788755, 
NA, NA, NA, 3.9851808825531)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

But my output constantly looks like this:

```
  Family         count  mean    sd
   <fct>          <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Adoxaceae          2  4.95  2.67
 2 Anacardiaceae      2  5.28  4.24
 3 Apiaceae           1 16.3  NA   
 4 Asteraceae         5 24.3  11.3 
 5 Cornaceae          1  5.75 NA   
 6 Ericaceae          1 15.1  NA   
 7 Fabaceae           3  7.75  3.18
 8 Oleaceae           1 44.4  NA   
 9 Pinaceae           1 29.6  NA   
10 Plantaginaceae     1  9.01 NA   
11 Rosaceae           4  5.7   3.99
```

The NAs should just be 0s no?

Comment: If you have a single observation, `sd` returns NA i.e. `sd(2)#
[1] NA` or with `sd(2, na.rm = TRUE)#
[1] NA`  You may need to check the source code of `var` about how the na.rm is called

Comment: So na.rm=TRUE won't convert those NAs to 0s?

Comment: `sd` uses `sqrt(var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), 
    na.rm = na.rm))` and if you check `var`, there are calls to `na.method <- pmatch(use, c("all.obs", "complete.obs", "pairwise.complete.obs", 
        "everything", "na.or.complete"))`

Comment: `na.rm = TRUE` is for the INPUT data, if your INPUT contains `NA`s they're not considered. The OUTPUT of `sd` is unaffected by this.

Comment: Oh I see I misunderstood how it worked. Okay thank you for clarifying this!

Comment: Except (as we **should**  know),   the variance has no meaning for a single value, and in fact the unbiased formula divides by   `(N-1)`  which is why the corrrect returned value is  `NA`  and not zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained by @akrun, `sd(..., na.rm = TRUE)` drops NA values when computing the standard deviation, but groups with a single value will still produce `NA`.

@CarlWitthoft points out that `NA` is the correct answer: while you *can* replace the `NA` values by zero, maybe you *shouldn't* (i.e., the estimate of the within-group variability of a group with only one sample can't be estimated ...)

---

If you've thought about it and decided that **it actually makes sense for your use case** to define `sd(numeric(0))` as 0, you could fix this by e.g.

```r
my_data |> tidyr::replace_na(list(sd=0))
```

Alternatively, you could write your own `sd()` wrapper:

```r
my_sd <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE) {
   if (length(x) <= 1) return(0)
   sd(x, na.rm = na.rm)
}
```

Comment: Good code but I am not a fan of allowing  the uneducated (i.e. the OP) to continue to do things wrong.   `NA` is the correct answer, not zero.